# Value arrangement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question on how "," versus what would be \n
In python 3.+

```
#There is technically a "\n" in between this two values (BA & BB)
BA=6 
BB=90
```

But shouldn't it be interpreted the same was as this?

```
BA,BB = 6,90
```

Correct? The reason I'm asking this is because of how this *while loop* is interpreting it.

```
a ,b = 0,1
while b <100:
    print(b)
    a,b = b, a+b
```

Is not the same as:

```
a=0
b=1    
while b <10:
    print(b)
    a=b
    b = a+b
```

The first *while loop* gives me a Fibonacci output but the second *while loop* gives me a duplication.
Output of second while loop:

```
1 
2 
4 
8 
4
```

Could some one explain?

Comment: I point you at [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) if you want to know specifics, but, no, they are not the same. the first variant is equivalent to `(a,b) = (b, a+b)`. The second , well, sets `a` to `b`, and then tries to add `a` (which is now `b`) to `b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the values of `a` and `b` are updated at the end of the statement, which means that you can pass the value of `b` to `a` before it becomes `a+b`.

In the first loop, here is what happens:

```
1    a becomes b=1 & b becomes a+b=0+1=1
2    a becomes b=1 & b becomes a+b=1+1=2
3    a becomes b=2 & b becomes a+b=1+2=3
4    a becomes b=3 & b becomes a+b=2+3=5
```

However, in the second loop, these events are separated, so:

```
1    a becomes b=1
     b becomes a+b=1+1=2
2    a becomes b=2
     b becomes a+b=2+2=4
3    a becomes b=4
     b becomes a+b=4+4=8
```

As you can see, in each iteration of the second loop, you are effectively just doubling the value of `b`.  If you wanted to avoid setting both variables on the same line, you would need to define a 3rd variable, which was equal to the old value of `a`:

```
a=0
b=1    
while b <100:
    print(b)
    old_a = a;
    a=b
    b = old_a+b
```

This loop will work as you expect.